# What kind of sequence/progression is this? What will be the answer to the question?

Tags: sequences-and-series, arithmetic-progressions, geometric-progressions

There are 20 urns such that the first urn contains 5 balls, the second contains 10 balls and in general the $k^{th}$ urn contains $2k + 1$ balls more that that in $(k - 1)^{th}$ urn. Then what is the total number of balls in all the urns?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Not AP, nor GP and not HP either. I don't have any idea what to do.

Comment: The $n$-th term of the sequence is $n^2+n+2.$

Comment: $a_n = 2n+1 + a_{n-1}$ - @Brian

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The $n$-th term of the sequence is $n^2+2n+2.$ Hence the total number of balls in the urns is $$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{20} (n^2+2n+2)=3330.$$

Comment: I don't think so. The third term is 17. Since 10 +(2*3+1)=17. But your sequence says the 3rd term is 14.

Comment: Yeah I have made a mistake. Now I hope it's correct.

Comment: @Abhinash Dutta have you checked my edited solution now?

Comment: Wow. You did it. It is correct. What type of sequence is it by the way? And what logic did you use to solve it?

Comment: It's an increasing sequence which is unbounded above.

Comment: The $n$-th term of the sequence is just $5+ \sum\limits_{k=2}^{n} (2n+1) = n^2 + 2n + 2.$

Comment: It seems to me that you are bengali @Abhinash Dutta. Isn't it so?

Comment: Yup. That's it.

Comment: What's that @Balakrishnan Rajan?

Comment: The answer I posted boils down to this. So I removed it and up voted this. You may want to add the details for the sake of completeness.

Comment: @Balakrishnan Rajan as far as I remember you wrote $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{20} a_n = 5 + \sum\limits_{n=2}^{20} (2n+1).$ Which is not correct. Pardon me please if I am wrong. You have the full right to write your own solution.

Comment: No. I understand. I meant $a_{20} $. But wrote $\sum_{n=1}^{20} a_n$. Oversight. It's wrong. No point in posting it. What I meant is post correction it becomes this. I wasn't implying that I was right.

Comment: @Dbchatto67 No, I am Assamese.

Comment: Oh! I see @Abhinash Dutta.

Comment: Thanks for answering.

Comment: You are most welcome @Abhinash Dutta.