# KVPY Question : Series and Progression

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, contest-math

There are $20$ urns such that the first urn contains $5$ balls, the second contains $10$ balls and in general the $k^{th}$ urn contains $2k+1$ balls more than that in the $(k-1)^{th}$ urn. Then the total number of balls in all the urns is:

I know that this question has been asked before ([What kind of sequence/progression is this? What will be the answer to the question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3166043/what-kind-of-sequence-progression-is-this-what-will-be-the-answer-to-the-questi)) , but I have quite not understood the solution and how the $n^{th}$ term has been found.

My approach goes forward like this, but I'm getting stuck at a point:

Given : In general the $k^{th}$ urn contains $2k+1$ balls more than that in the $(k-1)^{th}$ urn.

Using this info:

$3^{rd}$ urn contains : $10 + (2 \times 3 + 1)$ balls, $i.e.$ $17$ balls.

Let $k_i$ represent the natural number $i$.

Using this, the balls in $20^{th}$ urn are:

$5 + (2k_2+1) + (2k_3+1) + (2k_4+1) + (2k_5+1) + (2k_6+1) + ... +  (2k_{18}+1) + (2k_{19}+1)+ (2k_{20}+1)  $

Therefore total balls are:

$5\times 20 + 19(2k_2+1) + 18(2k_3+1) + 17(2k_4+1) + 16(2k_5+1) + 15(2k_6+1) + ... +  3(2k_{18}+1) + 2(2k_{19}+1)+ (2k_{20}+1)$

Which can further be written as:

$100 + \sum_{n=1}^{19} r +$

Not getting further. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT**

"Let $k_i$ represent the natural number $i$" is a step in the wrong direction.  Just call it $i$.

First thing to do is to get a formula for the number of balls in urn $k$.  Urn $1$ has $5$ balls, urn $2$ has $5+5$, urn $3$ has $5+5+7$, urn $4$ has $5+5+7+9$, and so on.  We can see that urn $1$ doesn't quite fit the pattern, but if $k>1$ then urn $k$ contains $$5+\sum_{i=2}^k(2i+1)$$ balls.  Can you compute this?